# Return different value if certain condition is true

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have this query:

```
select last_ddns_update_time 
from lu_camera cam 
where cam.unit_id='90016980' 
      and cam.device_id='2051'
      and cam.device_id not in (
                    select device_id 
                    from lu_camera_ext 
                    where unit_id=cam.unit_id 
                          and device_id=cam.device_id)
```

It currently only returns one variable (from a cell).  Is it possible to return two variables (one from a cell and one set inside the query itself)?

I want it so that if this part is true:

```
(select device_id 
 from lu_camera_ext 
 where unit_id=cam.unit_id 
       and device_id=cam.device_id)
```

Then return value A else return value B (`select last_ddns_update_time, new_value`).  I'm relatively new to SQL, so I'm sorry if this is a mega scrub question.

Something kind of like:

```
select last_ddns_update_time, new_value from lu_camera cam where cam.unit_id='90016980' and cam.device_id='2051' and cam.device_id 
and if (select device_id from lu_camera_ext where unit_id=cam.unit_id and device_id=cam.device_id) set new_value='a'
else set new_value='b'
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot grab data in your select from tables that are in your where clause. You just do not have access to them. However, by changing your query a little bit, you can do what you are asking. Instead of having the sub-select in your where clause, let's move it to the select part of your query (WHAT?!). That's right, you can have a sub-select in your select.

Since you are checking if the cam.device_id is in your sub-select, I am going to assume that you want the 'new_value' if the id is in the select, otherwise you want the last_ddns_update_time. It looks like this:

```
Select isnull((select new_value
               from lu_camera_ext 
               where unit_id=cam.unit_id 
               and device_id=cam.device_id
               and cam.device_id = device_id)
        , last_ddns_update_time)
from lu_camera cam 
where cam.unit_id='90016980' 
      and cam.device_id='2051'
```

So what is happening is, you are looking for that new value from lu_camera_ext if the cam.device_id is in the table. If the device_id is not returned with your sub-select, instead null will be returned. Then the isnull evaluates the returned value. If you get null back, then instead last_ddns_update_time is returned as per usual.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL equiv to If/Else is the CASE keyword.  Also, the query would be easier if you used an "outer join".  Try this:

```
select last_ddns_update_time,
    CASE WHEN ext.device_id IS NULL THEN 'b' ELSE 'a' END as new_value
from lu_camera cam LEFT JOIN lu_camera_ext ext ON cam.unit_id=ext.unit_id 
    and cam.device_id=ext.device_id
where cam.unit_id='90016980' 
    and cam.device_id='2051'
```